# How to publish my multi project solution to Azure correctly

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-code

I have a visual studio solution with:

- a Functions project (for Azure Functions),
- an Email Service connecting to a mailing service,
- API for my database (has controllers and unused views and an index.html),
- Identity Server project (has controllers and unused views and an index.html),
- React frontend ((I edit and run from VSCode, all other projects in solution from Visual Studio)

Do I have to push these up separately to azure, or do I simply push it all up to an Azure Web App (minus the database). How to i let it know to launch the the react index versus either of the indexes in the API or Identity projects?

Answer (score 0):

No you can do it with single repo/Mono Repo itself. You can handle multiple build that is located in the same repo and use the path filter. Powershell gives you lot of flexibility to do that :)

Go through this [blog](https://dev.to/nikolicbojan/azure-devops-yaml-build-for-mono-repository-with-multiple-projects-146g?fbclid=IwAR0oAbPELgEn7M2AbplsKBGwo3g1_VWJ4CLJav7euuZ7CqLS4v9ceZ7JvZg)